# VSCode installed with Anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not open, permission denied error

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, microsoft, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I just installed VScode with anaconda on Ubuntu 18.04 and after installation it won't open.

I did the same on Ubuntu 16 LTS but it worked fine. I tried to uninstall it from anaconda navigator and install it with [this procedure](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) but it's still not working. When I click on the icon just nothing happens.

```
 code --verbose 

Gtk-Message: 17:32:24.579: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar" 
Gtk-Message: 17:32:24.621: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" [main 4:32:25 PM] Startup error: ,,
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mohsen74x/.config/Code/CachedData',Error: EACCES: permission denied,
mkdir '/home/mohsen74x/.config/Code/logs/20180528T173225' [main 4:32:25 PM] Lifecycle#kill()
```

Comment: Any error messages? Try `code --verbose`.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen
code --verbose
Gtk-Message: 17:32:24.579: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 17:32:24.621: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[main 4:32:25 PM] Startup error: ,,Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mohsen74x/.config/Code/CachedData',Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/mohsen74x/.config/Code/logs/20180528T173225'
[main 4:32:25 PM] Lifecycle#kill()

thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are running with sudo?

Comment: vscode should not be run with `sudo` @proneon

Comment: But the message just says " permission denied " .

Comment: Also I had once the same issue and it worked fine when I run with sudo. But I had this problem in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: That's perhaps becos OP might have installed it wrong or there are issues with with some startup files. Programs are installed usually with sudo but should run without it

Comment: Thanks. I just fixed the errors shows in code --verbose and it works now

Comment: @proneon in my case i give the permission with 
sudo chown -R mohsen74x:staff

Comment: @mohsen74persian please post it as an answer to your OP, glad you fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar-gtk2
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

and for permission:

```
sudo chown -R mohsen74x:staff /home/mohsen74x/.config/Code
```

this solved my problem.